# ExtJS6 DragZone on Grid with CheckBox Model

Tags: extjs, drag-and-drop

I have a grid which is enabled with Ext.dd.DragZone.  I am dragging records from the grid and dropping them on various nodes in a tree panel.  Single record drops work great; however, I am unable to successfully drag multiple records to a tree node...only one record gets processed.  The DragZone is instantiated on the render of the view by the following function:

```
renderDD: function(view){
        grid = view.up('gridpanel');
        grid.dragZone = Ext.create('Ext.dd.DragZone',view.el,{
            onBeforeDrag: function(data,e){                
                return data.messagedata.foldertype==2 ? false : true;
            },
            getDragData: function(e){
                var sourceEl = e.getTarget(view.itemSelector,10),d;                
                if(sourceEl){
                    d = sourceEl.cloneNode(true);
                    d.id = Ext.id();
                    return(view.dragData = {
                            sourceEl: sourceEl,
                            repairXY: Ext.fly(sourceEl).data,
                            ddel: d,
                            messagedata:view.getRecord(sourceEl).data                            
                    });
                }
            },            
            getRepairXY: function(){
                return this.dragData.repairXY;
            }
        });
    },
    ...
```

Can any one help me on dragging multiple records using DragZone and DropZone (not the grid plugins). Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would most likely do something like [this Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1qj4) if you can't use the plugins.  You can customize how you want the drag to look with your own HTML.  I'm not really sure if this is the proper way to do it, but it was my first stab at it.  Hopefully it helps you figure out how you want to tackle this.

The reason your code isn't working is because you're only getting a single record.  Instead, I'm making use of the [`getSelection`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.selection.RowModel.html#cfg-mode) method provided by the grid class, which returns all of the selected items I've selected in the grid because I've created a [`rowmodel`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.selection.RowModel.html#cfg-mode) selection model with mode [`MULTI`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.selection.RowModel.html#cfg-mode).

```
getDragData: function (event, b, c) {
    var selection = view.getSelection();
    var sourceEl = document.createElement('div');
    sourceEl.innerHTML = 'blah';
    if (selection) {
        var d = sourceEl.cloneNode(true);
        d.id = Ext.id();
        return {
            sourceEl: sourceEl,
            repairXY: Ext.fly(sourceEl).getXY(),
            ddel: d,
            records: selection
        };
    }
},
```